# Crontab GUI for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, cron

Is there any app for the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (server, no visual interface) in order to easily manage `crontab`? Maybe a daemon running in background and access to it via a web browser?
Using `crontab -e` is not working anymore for me because I have over 100 lines with crons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Crontab UI](https://github.com/alseambusher/crontab-ui). This is something I made to allow easy and safe management of crontab.

[image: Sample Workflow of Crontab UI]

These are some of the features provided by it:

1. Easy setup
2. Safe adding, deleting or pausing jobs. Easy to maintain hundreds of jobs.
3. Backup your crontabs.
4. Export crontab and deploy on other machines without much hassle.

Read [this](http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.in/2015/06/crontab-ui-easy-and-safe-way-to-manage.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for doing that ! You are a lightsaber !

Answer (score 1):

## Web-based Administration

You can try amongst the web-based server administration panels that are available for Ubuntu. [Ajenti](http://ajenti.org/) and [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) are two such programs that do support cron - I personally will recommend Ajenti.

Comment: I'm not sure I really want such a complex app for a small task. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AlexRose Sure, you can also try SSH with X11 forwarding with a normal cron GUI application like gnome-schedule, but then the server needs X11.