# Scheduling deja-dup to start later

Tags: deja-dup

When I open "Backups, Scheduling" in 14.04, it gives me a choice between "Every Week" and "Every Day."

I want to schedule a backup every week, beginning at a time when I will be asleep.  But the "Overview" allows me only to "Back Up Now."

How do I schedule the first backup to begin on a later day, at a time of my own choosing?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use `cron` where `cron` is a scheulder for Linux.

Easily run this command to enter a new entry

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This wil open a the default editor to edit crontab. If you save and exit the editor, all your cronjobs are saved into crontab. Cronjobs are written in the following format:

```
* * * * * /some-script.sh
```

As you can see there are 5 stars. The stars are in the following order:

```
minute (from 0 to 59)
hour (from 0 to 23)
day of month (from 1 to 31)
month (from 1 to 12)
day of week (from 0 to 6) (0=Sunday)
```

So in your case

```
0 2 * * 0 /usr/bin/deja-dup --backup
```

This means it will run the backup in SunDays of every month at 2:00 AM

you can edit time as you wish

If you like GUI way you can check this [Crontab GUI for Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422540/crontab-gui-for-ubuntu-12-04)